# How to use AsyncTask in Android application

Tags: android, json, database, android-asynctask

I'm developing an application for android, my problem is the implementation of AsyncTask, what i must do is "simple":

This part of function is used to get information from a database, after data loading, the informations are showed in a table, I would implement a function that allows me to show a progress bar during the retrieval of information (read server)

```
try {
    String url_img = null;
    String path = "MY FANTASTIC PATH";

    /*READSERVER RETURN JSON STRING THAT CONTAIN SOME IMFORMATION*/

    ReadServer read = new ReadServer();
    String result = read.readserver("list_news","homepage");

    TableLayout MainTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_table); 
    JSONArray Jobj = new JSONArray(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < Jobj.length(); i++){
     TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext()); 
     row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     row.setPadding(0, 14, 2, 14);

     JSONObject news_preview = Jobj.getJSONObject(i);
     Integer news_id = news_preview.getInt("id_articolo");
     String news_title = news_preview.getString("titolo");
     String news_image = news_preview.getString("immagine");



     //Check if image url is relative or absolute 
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(news_image);

     if(m.matches() == false){
       url_img = path+news_image;
     }else if(m.matches() == true){
       url_img = news_image;
     }

     //Call Html Parser to parse text
     HtmlParser parsed_string = new HtmlParser();
     Spanned title_nohtml = parsed_string.htmlparser(news_title);

     //Thumb
     ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
     img.setMaxHeight(140); img.setMaxWidth(140);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url_img).getContent());
     img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     LayoutParams params =  new TableRow.LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     //Clickable title
     final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
     txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL );
     txt.setLayoutParams(params); txt.setTextSize(18); txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     txt.setId(news_id); txt.setText(title_nohtml); txt.setClickable(true);

     row.addView(img);
     row.addView(txt);  
     MainTable.addView(row);

     txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherPages.class);
       Bundle extras = new Bundle();
       extras.putString("Boolean","1");
       extras.putInt("id_news", txt.getId());
       intent.putExtras(extras);
       startActivity(intent);
      }
     });
    }    
   }catch(Exception e){
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertDialog.setTitle("Si è verificato un errore");
     alertDialog.setMessage("Errore 001" +"\n"+"Non è stato possibile soddisfare la tua richiesta, riprova più tardi.");
     alertDialog.show();        
   }
  }else{
      connectivityMessage("Nessuna connessione presente, assicurati di avere il traffico dati oppure il Wi-Fi attivato e riprova."); 
  }
```

I know that i must use this code but i dont know how implements, can anyone help me ?

```
GetNews getNewsTask = new GetNews().execute();
 private class GetNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
  private ProgressDialog progress = null;

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // do something

        return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(
        MainActivity.this, null, "Caricamento notizie...");
        super.onPreExecute();
      }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
      }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       }
      }
```

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
 private class GetNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
  private ProgressDialog progress = null;

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Looper.prepare(); //MUST BE ADDED
    ReadServer read = new ReadServer();
    String result = read.readserver("list_news","homepage");
    System.out.println("DEBUG"+result);
    return result;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(
    MainActivity.this, null, "Caricamento notizie");
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
     String url_img = null;
     String path = "http://www.MYFANTASTICPATH.it";

     TableLayout MainTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
     JSONArray Jobj = new JSONArray(result);

     for (int i = 0; i < Jobj.length(); i++) {
     TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
     row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     row.setPadding(0, 14, 2, 14);

     JSONObject news_preview = Jobj.getJSONObject(i);
     Integer news_id = news_preview.getInt("id_articolo");
     String news_title = news_preview.getString("titolo");
     String news_image = news_preview.getString("immagine");

     // Check if image url is relative or absolute
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(news_image);

     if (m.matches() == false) {
         url_img = path + news_image;
     } else if (m.matches() == true) {
        url_img = news_image;
     }

     // Call Html Parser to parse text
     HtmlParser parsed_string = new HtmlParser();
     Spanned title_nohtml = parsed_string.htmlparser(news_title);

     // Thumb
     ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
     img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
     img.setMaxHeight(140);
     img.setMaxWidth(140);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url_img).getContent());
     img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     // Clickable title
     final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
     txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
     txt.setLayoutParams(params);
     txt.setTextSize(18);
     txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
     txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     txt.setId(news_id);
     txt.setText(title_nohtml);
     txt.setClickable(true);

     row.addView(img);
     row.addView(txt);
     MainTable.addView(row);

     txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherPages.class);
       Bundle extras = new Bundle();
       extras.putString("Boolean", "1");
       extras.putInt("id_news", txt.getId());
       intent.putExtras(extras);
       startActivity(intent);
      }
     });
    }
   }catch (Exception e) {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
     alertDialog.setTitle("Si è verificato un errore");
     alertDialog.setMessage("Errore 001" + "\n" + "Non è stato possibile soddisfare la tua richiesta, riprova più tardi.");
     alertDialog.show();
    }
    progress.dismiss();
   }

   @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
     super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
   }
```

Comment: @Sukan look my edit, is it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ondoInbackground` you want to do all the main tasks in the background ....

`onPostexecute` you display all the results from the doinbackground

P.S : If u want to access to UI,do it in `onPostexecute` or `onProgressupdate`

Answer (score 0):

Simply write wherever you want to use it.

```
GetNews getNewsTask = new GetNews().execute();
```

Following are words of Android Developer site.

> **onPreExecute()** invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
> by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
>
> **doInBackground(Params...)** invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
> to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
> parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
> result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
> passed back to the last step. This step can also use
> publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
> These values are published on the UI thread, in the
> onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
>
> **onProgressUpdate(Progress...)** invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
> undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
> user interface while the background computation is still executing.
> For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
> a text field.
>
> **onPostExecute(Result)** invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
> computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Source: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this I edit your code and prepare a demo that how  to use asynctask

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetNews getNews = new GetNews();
        getNews.execute();
    }

    private class GetNews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ReadServer read = new ReadServer();
            String result = read.readserver("list_news", "homepage");
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Caricamento notizie...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                String url_img = null;
                String path = "MY FANTASTIC PATH";

                /* READSERVER RETURN JSON STRING THAT CONTAIN SOME IMFORMATION */

                ReadServer read = new ReadServer();
                String result = read.readserver("list_news", "homepage");

                TableLayout MainTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
                JSONArray Jobj = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < Jobj.length(); i++) {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    row.setPadding(0, 14, 2, 14);

                    JSONObject news_preview = Jobj.getJSONObject(i);
                    Integer news_id = news_preview.getInt("id_articolo");
                    String news_title = news_preview.getString("titolo");
                    String news_image = news_preview.getString("immagine");

                    // Check if image url is relative or absolute
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(news_image);

                    if (m.matches() == false) {
                        url_img = path + news_image;
                    } else if (m.matches() == true) {
                        url_img = news_image;
                    }

                    // Call Html Parser to parse text
                    HtmlParser parsed_string = new HtmlParser();
                    Spanned title_nohtml = parsed_string.htmlparser(news_title);

                    // Thumb
                    ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                    img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    img.setMaxHeight(140);
                    img.setMaxWidth(140);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url_img).getContent());
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                    // Clickable title
                    final TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    txt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    txt.setLayoutParams(params);
                    txt.setTextSize(18);
                    txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    txt.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    txt.setId(news_id);
                    txt.setText(title_nohtml);
                    txt.setClickable(true);

                    row.addView(img);
                    row.addView(txt);
                    MainTable.addView(row);

                    txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherPages.class);
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                            extras.putString("Boolean", "1");
                            extras.putInt("id_news", txt.getId());
                            intent.putExtras(extras);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Si è verificato un errore");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Errore 001" + "\n" + "Non è stato possibile soddisfare la tua richiesta, riprova più tardi.");
                alertDialog.show();

            }
            progress.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the code that fetches data from database in **doInBackground()** .This process will be run in the background. Since you want to show the progress bar during the retrival of information you have to include the code showing progress bar in **onProgressUpdate()** which is run on the **UI** thread.You have to call **PublishProgres** manually from **doInBackground()** to publish one or more progress units through **onProgressUpdate()**. **doInBackground()** invoked on background thread after **onPreExecute()**. After the retrival of information you can display the data using **onPostExecute()** which is **UI thread**. Mainly **Async Task** is used to perform process on background thread which is not related to **UI** instead of the Main thread running with **UI**